# X-inactivation in ovaries

Tags: genetics, chromosome, epigenetics

**Background**

In all [eutherian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eutheria) (mammals excluding the marsupials), the female (who is $XX$ for the pair of sexual chromosomes) inactivates one of her $X$. This is called [dosage compensation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dosage_compensation). This inactivation occurs at a given time during the development when randomly one $X$ is silenced. The daughters of this cell inherit the $X$-inactivation pattern epigenetically, which results in some part of a tissue having the maternal $X$ inactivated while others having the paternal $X$ inactivated (daughters of some other cell which silenced the paternal $X$). This process yield to the famous [turtoiseshell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tortoiseshell_cat) coat in female cats.

**Question**

*In short*

Assuming X-inactivation occurred in the lineage of the oogonia/oocytes, when does the X-inactivation and X-reactivation occur in the lineage of the oocytes?

*A bit developed*

Are the X inactivated as well in primary oocytes? If not, is the $X$ inactivated in the secondary oocytes in a primary follicle? If not, did the diploid mother cells of the secondary oocytes have one $X$-inactivated? If yes, did all diploid mother cells of oocytes have the same $X$ inactivated (inactivation occurred relatively early in the development or is there an imprinting) or did the mother cells of oocytes differ in the $X$ they have inactivated (inactivation occurred relatively late in the development)

Comment: *I'll post an elaborate answer in some time. Little occupied now*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See these two papers:

- [Early Loss of Xist RNA Expression and Inactive X Chromosome Associated Chromatin Modification in Developing Primordial Germ Cells](http://www.plosone.org/article/info%3Adoi%2F10.1371%2Fjournal.pone.0000860#abstract0)
- [X Chromosome Reactivation Initiates in Nascent Primordial Germ Cells in Mice](http://www.plosgenetics.org/article/info%3Adoi%2F10.1371%2Fjournal.pgen.0030116)

Basically it happens just before the meiosis.